# Exporting .blend adds an "emissive" value even without emission shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export, light, .fbx

When I export my object from Blender, it exports with an "emissive" property under materials with a value of [0.8,0.8,0.8]. I cannot for the life of me find how to set this value to 0. When I'm viewing the object in the 3D viewport, I am able to see it even with no light source, which sort of confirms that the object is somehow emissive. As seen below, the Emit property is 0, so I'm not sure if this is like a texture thing or what.

The problem exists regardless of Blender Render or Cycles Render.

Here's my .blend file: https://ufile.io/i5z2f

Here is a screenshot of my material properties:
[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Here's a JSON version of the FBX with the problematic emissive value:

```
{
        "id": "Material.002", 
        "ambient": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], // needs to be 0,0,0!
        "opacity":  1.000000, 
        "specular": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000], 
        "shininess":  0.000000, 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "Texture.003", 
                "filename": "FlakCannon_D.png", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }, 
            {
                "id": "Texture.003", 
                "filename": "FlakCannon_D.png", 
                "type": "SPECULAR"
            }, 
            {
                "id": "Texture.003", 
                "filename": "FlakCannon_D.png", 
                "type": "REFLECTION"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Info:
Blender version: 2.79
FBX Export Addon: 3.7.17

Comment: Please provide more detail, eg version of fbx exporter addon, and blender version.

Comment: Ok, I have 4.13.1 for 2.80 and 3.10.0 for 2.79.  The 2.79 version (on a very cursory look) appears to set `Emissive` to (0, 0, 0).  Have you checked to see if it is simply set as  a copy of diffuse color?

Comment: @batFINGER no, funnily enough the diffuse in the file doesn't even match the diffuse set in the material properties. I may try to update to the latest Blender to see if that fixes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSON file, it looks like you use LibGDX fbx-conv tool.

I'm facing the same issue and i can confirm it's not related to Blender FBX exporter. More information and workaround can be found here : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5529

Comment: Thanks! I actually downloaded the sources for FBX-conv and made my own version of it that just sets the emissive property to 0, which fixes the issue. I can send you the .exe if you'd like. From your git issue page, it looks like you have the correct solution, and I can try subbing the correct code in and sending that binary to you, if you haven't already. Then we could host a fork for any other folks having the problem if the devs don't get around to it.

Comment: cool! i'll wait the next official version. No need to fork, just PR the fix to official repo, i'm pretty sure it'll be merged soon. Thanks in advance for your fix.
BTW could you vote for my answer to make it as accepted please :-)